# How to replace each element in a numpy array with multiple values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array with size n * m, and I need to replace each value with 2 valus and result in an array with size n * 2m.

Replace pattern:`1` with `[1,0]`, `2` with `[0,1]` and `0` with `[0,0]`

Input: `[[1,0,2],[2,2,1]]`

Desired Output: `[[1,0,0,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1,1,0]]`

It can be easily done with a for loop, however I'm trying to find a 'numpy' way of doing it, to achieve maximum efficiency.

```
res = np.zeros((arr.shape[0],arr.shape[1]*2))
for index, row in enumerate(arr):
    temp = np.array([])
    for e in row:
        if e == 1:
            temp = np.append(temp,[1,0])
        elif e == 2:
            temp = np.append(temp,[0,1])
        else:
            temp = np.append(temp,[0,0])
    res[index] = temp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have values 0, 1, 2, I would use a reference array to map the values by indexing:

```
a = np.array([[1,0,2],[2,2,1]])
mapper = np.array([[0, 0],  # position 0
                   [1, 0],  # position 1
                   [0, 1]]) # position 2

out = mapper[a].reshape((len(a), -1))
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```